# Manage JAVA processes under Windows

Tags: java, windows, process, monitoring

How do I manage Java processes in Windows environment. What I need is to see, what parameters Java process was started with (e.g. Main class) and be able to shut process down.

Comment: what do you mean by java processes? the threads you started? or the running java application?

Comment: But you can't. There is only 'java.exe' or 'javaw.exe', once for each process that is running.

Comment: check for java.exe,javaw.exe java  applications.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `java.exe` , `javaw.exe` and `javaws.exe`.

**java.exe**

`java.exe` is a `Win32` console application. This is provided as a helper so that, instead of using `jvm.dll` we can execute java classes. As it is a `Win32` console application, obviously it is associated with a console and it launches it when executed.

**javaw.exe**

`javaw.exe` is very similar to `java.exe`. It can be considered as a parallel twin. It is a `Win32` GUI application. This is provided as a helper so that application launches its own GUI window and will not launch a console. Whenever we want to run a GUI based application and don’t require a command console, we can use this as application launcher.

**javaws.exe**

`javaws.exe` is used to launch a java application that is distributed through web.

For more info **[REFER](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-vs-javaw-vs-javaws/)**